# Having difficulty with unwrapping a simple part of an object

Tags: uv

I am having lots of troubles unwrapping an object. I tried to start simple by selecting only part of the object and unwrapping that, but even something simple is not turning out intended.

Here is the simple part of the object being unwrapped:

[image]

I have tried Applying the Scale, using Ctrl-A > Scale and I have marked seams as shown below:

[image]

And here are the UVs after choosing "Unwrap" from the "UV Mapping" menu:

[image]

I have no idea why it looks this way. Can anyone add any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44432/how-do-uv-texture-seams-work

Comment: Thanks for the links to previous posts. I tried Applying the Scale and have edited my question to show the marked seams I am using. The results are no different though.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

UVs after choosing "Unwrap" from the "UV Mapping" might not be accurate most of the times so it would be better to choose "Smart UV Project" instead of "Unwrap".

Comment: When seams were marked UVs won't be inaccurate any more than those done with Smart UV since under the hood both use the same method